# is it nook and corner or nook and cranny?

Tags: grammar

most Indians  use the idiom "every nook and corner instead of every nook and cranny.Is it acceptable in native English countries like England?
 i have heard sentences like I searched every nook and cornerbut I could not find it.Is the idiom acceptable ?

i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [the history](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=every%20nook%20and%20corner%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20cranny&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20corner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20cranny%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20corner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20cranny%3B%2Cc0) of the two forms...
[image]

I can't even begin to speculate on why *mainstream* Anglophones switched their preference so decisively from ***corner*** to ***cranny*** in the first half of the last century. Well, maybe I can - perhaps we all just liked the "quaintness" of these unusual (almost "dialectal" nouns). But I think [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cranny%2Cnook%20and%20cranny&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccranny%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnook%20and%20cranny%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccranny%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnook%20and%20cranny%3B%2Cc0) is also relevant...

[image]

What that second chart shows is that over 70% of all instances of the relatively uncommon word ***cranny*** now occur in the "fixed phrase" *[every] nook and cranny*. It's the same story with ***nook***, which is also relatively uncommon today outside this fixed form.

Note that the *actual* shift in preference will be even more extreme than that implied by the charts, since many of the more recent hits for the "original, obsolete" form will be direct quotes from (or misdated reprints of) much earlier instances.

---

Since becoming a regular here on ELL, I've become aware that "Indian English" often retains usages from Victorian times long after they're discarded by Brits and Americans - but the reason for *that* is a matter of culture / history, not linguistics / grammar.

Is it "acceptable"? The IE form will certainly be easily *understood*, but I think almost all mainstream Anglophones would think it was at the very least "odd". And if they knew the speaker wasn't a native Anglophone, they might be tempted to (helpfully) point out the "correct" version. Despite what my first chart might suggest, nowhere near 30% of native speakers today (probably not even **3%**) would *ever* have encountered *every nook and **corner***.

Comment: thank mr Fumble for your timely and comprehensi ve answer which help a lot like Indian English teachers like me

Comment: I take it that although you *teach* [Indian] English, you're not yourself a native *Anglophone*. But I would be interested to know if you (and others in your line of work) have a view on whether you actually *want* to teach students "English as currently used in India", or whether you'd rather move more towards "mainstream" English. Personally, I'd be sorry to lose some features of current IE (the use of ***prepone*** as the antonym of ***postpone*** is one example that comes to mind! :)

Comment: Mr Fumble. I try to teach British English but not Indian English though Iam not a native English speaker or teacher we teach all Indianisms like prepone which is an analogy of post war and prewar periods

Answer (score 2):

Define **acceptable**.  The phrase is idiomatic, so it is ultimately specific to the listener.

As a native British English speaker, I'd certainly know what you *meant*, but I'd hear the word *corner* and think you'd got the idiom wrong, because I have never heard it expressed as *"every nook and **corner**"*—only *"every nook and **cranny**"*.

That said, I don't regularly converse with Indian English speakers, and they may well accept **corner** over **cranny**.

If you intend to be natural-sounding to a British English speaker, stick to the British English idiom.

(The [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=every+nook+and+cranny%2Cevery+nook+and+corner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20cranny%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20corner%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20cranny%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20corner%3B%2Cc0) is interesting, though, suggesting that *nook and corner* might once have been far more common...)

Comment: Thank you mr Jim. i know the idiom every nook and corner is an Indianism. The dictionary says nook and crany but most indians say nook and corner

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this older version of the phrase in a text written by an American (1830s): [https://wwnorton.com/college/history/eamerica/media/ch12/resources/documents/morse.htm#:~:text=Raised%20in%20a%20deeply%20religious,foundational%20ideas%20for%20the%20telegraph](https://wwnorton.com/college/history/eamerica/media/ch12/resources/documents/morse.htm#:%7E:text=Raised%20in%20a%20deeply%20religious,foundational%20ideas%20for%20the%20telegraph)
Ended up here. I know FumbleFingers provided a very detailed explanation which I read with pleasure. Simply wanted to add that it looks like the American English also used "nook and corner". Which is to be expected, of course. But expressions like this are not necessarily Victorian.